# Access specific element of array from list django

Tags: python, django

I have queryset like this in my view.py:

```
  SomeValue = list(a.objects.filter(x=x_number, timestamp__gte=a_time, timestamp__lte=b_time) \
            .order_by('timestamp').values_list('timestamp', 'some_index').annotate(
            some1=dosomething('some_index'),
            some2=dosomething('some_index_2'),
            combined_some=(F('some1') + F('some2'))
        ))
```

So SomeValue looks like this:

```
SomeValue = [(datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 20, 23, 53, 51, tzinfo=<UTC>), 2L, 10.1, 2.4, 12.5), (datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 20, 23, 54, 51, tzinfo=<UTC>), 8L, 5.5, 6.4, 11.9), (datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 20, 23, 55, 51, tzinfo=<UTC>), 4L, 7.2, 2.0, 9.2),...]
```

My goal is to access SomeValue and get combined_some like this:

```
combined_some = [(datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 20, 23, 53, 51, tzinfo=<UTC>), 12.5), (datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 20, 23, 54, 51, tzinfo=<UTC>), 11.9), (datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 20, 23, 55, 51, tzinfo=<UTC>), 9.2),...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
combined_some = [(i[0], i[-1]) for i in SomeValue]
```